# How could I access to part of localStorage data and render them in Backbone app?

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I use localStorage to save the app data of my Backbone app. In my router, I use `this.collection.fetch()` to get the data from localStorage and render them. But `this.collection.fetch()` actually will fetch all the data in my localStorage space and render them all in View. What I want to do is to get the localStorage data first and filter them, then use these filtered part to render the View. Is it possibile to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you probably `bind` the view to the `reset` event of the collection.

```
this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this)
```

If you want to take more control against what to render (manual rendering not binded to events), you should avoid binding that events and call `render` method when you need it after doing proper filtering of collection.