# How to filter the localStorage data before I use it in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I use localStorage to persist the data of my Backbone app. But every time I use `this.collection.fetch()` to get the data, I want to filter them first and then just use part of the data to render my View. I tried to use ajax `data`options in `fetch` intending to filter the data, but it doesn't work. Could someone give me some idea on this?

Comment: why 2 posting for same question...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405963/how-could-i-access-to-part-of-localstorage-data-and-render-them-in-backbone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can filter the data. There are multiple ways to do this, so you need to better explain what you mean by filter the data. Assuming everything is working ok and you are parsing valid all valid models after you `fetch` I would recommend filtering the data in the `render()` method of the collection's view. Something as simple as this might work:

```
render: function() {
  this.collection.each(function(model) {
      if(model.something > somethingElse) {
         // render the model
         ...
      }
  })
},
```

if you mean that you don't want all the fetched data to be part of the the collection ever then you'll want to overwrite the collections parse method. It is passed the raw data that comes from the local storage and you need to return the collections data. See [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-parse)

Comment: What I mean is to use some filter to fetch just part of the data. I think that would be more efficient than retrieving all the data in the colletion first and then filtering them, right? Is there some way to just fetch part of the data?

Comment: Hm, I don't think you want to do that. Keep in mind, fetching from local storage is super fast and  _premature optimization is the root of all evil_. BUT if you must, take a look at this library: http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/